# using sylius_resource_sort with indexByTaxon action

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to add sorting to my Product:indexByTaxon action using sylius_resource_sort
I set "sortable" to true for resources. It seems though that this action doesn't support sorting at any point yet.

What would be the best apporach here? Should I replace it with modified Product:indexAction and add taxon as a criteria?

Answer (score 0):

That twig extension does not work with relationship, first you need to sort on a virtual property :

```
{{ sylius_resource_sort('my_taxon_property') }}
```

After that, you need to override your repository define your own method and play with sorting. You can have a look to the method findBy()?